# Rails app with puma on Ubuntu server freezes after a while

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, puma

I've mounted an Ubuntu Server VM to host my app.

The app works perfectly after I start it. After a while of inactivity (around 5 min with no requests) the app stops responding when I send requests to it.
The server logs:

```
Started GET "/" for 190.104.243.172 at 2016-05-11 13:22:46 +0000
```

And nothing more. It should log:

```
Started GET "/" for 190.104.243.172 at 2016-05-11 13:22:46 +0000
Processing by DashboardController#root as HTML
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 0ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
Started GET "/users/sign_in" for 190.104.243.172 at 2016-05-11 13:24:16 +0000
...
```

It's like it's not processing the request once it gets it.

This is my puma.rb config file

```
threads_count = Integer(ENV['MAX_THREADS'] || 16)
threads threads_count, threads_count
workers 1


preload_app!

rackup      DefaultRackup
port        ENV['PORT']     || 3000
environment ENV['RACK_ENV'] || 'development'

on_worker_boot do
  ActiveSupport.on_load(:active_record) do
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
  end
end

before_fork do
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.disconnect!
end
```

If I change the number of workers to 2 for example, the first request after 5 minutes works. If I then wait 5 more minutes, it freezes. So definitely must be something with workers hanging or not loading properly.

This is what I get when I do `ps -aux | grep puma`

```
user 57674  1.2 11.0 1003076 189780 ?      Ssl  16:14   0:12 puma 3.4.0 (tcp://0.0.0.0:3000) [be-better-hotels]                                                                         
user 57771  0.4 14.4 1497004 247484 ?      Sl   16:15   0:04 puma: cluster worker 0: 57674 [be-better-hotels]
```

EDIT: after like 30 minutes of making a request to the hanged server, the client gets a 500 Internal Server Error and the server shows this error message:

```
PG::UnableToSend (SSL SYSCALL error: EOF detected):
```

And a very large stack trace.

Comment: I think I have faced a similar problem a while back, can't quite remember though. Can you elaborate on your Server setup? Web server as load balancer / application server numbers? Also you can run `ps -ax | grep puma` to check on the worker processes. I'm suspecting that the worker processes die or get killed by something after a timeout.

Comment: I've edited with the `ps -aux | grep puma output` what else do you need me to show?

Comment: Same thing happening to me. May I suggest putting a bounty on this question?

Answer (score -1):

I went through the same issue on DO droplets with pure RAM instance.. all I did -- added swap.

Comment: I'm sorry but creating a swap partition did not help.
At least following this guide: http://serverfault.com/questions/695616/how-to-create-a-swap-for-azure-ubuntu-vm